# Custom Ringtones & AlertTones locations for macOS Sierra and High Sierra?

Tags: messages, ringtones, alert

Since Yosemite the only way to add custom ringtones was to drop them into:
`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Ringtones`

Is this location still our only option for adding custom ringtones to macOS or is there a new ~/Library/ location available to users?

I've had no luck isolating anything within `~/Library` that indicates that it is a ringtone storage location for Messages.app, etc.

Additionally, there is also an `AlertTones` folder in the above parent folder location:
`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AlertTones`

It appears that both of these will likely have to be remapped to something like `~/Music/Tones/Ringtones` & `~/Music/Tones/AlertTones`